# Facebook Shared Album Permissions

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, permissions

I have a shared album, with multiple contributors. When I go to pull back my photos from that album, I see none listed. There are definitely photos in the album, and I am an administrator. Using Koala we're querying for pictures using something like:

```
graph = Koala::Facebook::API.new(facebook_token)
graph.fql_query("SELECT pid, src_big FROM photo WHERE aid = #{album_id} limit 1000")
```

My app has **user_photos** and **friends_photos** permissions. Do shared albums need different permissions?  Am I missing something?

Comment: Could you share the code snippet that, you are using to fetch the Shared albums? (would be more helpful)

Comment: Updated. Thanks for taking a look.